# WPF Unit Testing - OnstartUp method

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing

I need to write unit test methods for `OnStartUp` method.

As it is a `protected` method, how do I access and test it?

```
protected override void OnStartUp(StartupEventArgs s)
{

}
```

Comment: You should only test public methods.

Comment: What do you want to test in OnStartUp(). What Code do you have show that first

Comment: The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete and would require too many questions to clarify what is being asked. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to better understand and reproduce your problem.

Comment: You shouldn't test this method. If you really need to access it during a test you can try "System.Type.InvokeMember(...)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, any people that tell you that `you should only test public methods` are using unit tests wrong.
You need to think for yourself what do unit tests give your code base. I am a firm believer that unit tests create a behavioural test harness that ensures that anything someone typed into a text editor stays exactly the same, unless it is a business approved change. This basically means that you need to test ALL the things.

Secondly, for `protected` methods in non`sealed` classes, you can simply inherit the class with another, test-only class, and expose a public invoker on it.

Like so:

```
public class TestWrapper : BaseClass {
    public void OnStartupInvoker(StartupEventArgs s)
    {
       OnStartUp(s);
    }
}

// And then in test

var target = new TestWrapper();
target.OnStartupInvoker(null); 
// it has been called!
```